# LIBGDX Input - Number of fingers touching the screen

Tags: android, libgdx

I wonder know How to get the **total number** of fingers **touching** the screen on my game.

Thanks you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use an [`InputProcessor`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) for event-based input processing, just increment a counter at `touchDown` and decrement the counter at `touchUp`.

If you're using [`Gdx.input`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html) for polling-based input processing, use the [`isTouched(int)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#isTouched%28int%29) call to test if pointer N is down.  The libGDX implementation [tracks at most 20 pointers](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidInput.java#L94).  I don't think any hardware supports that many (and your game may have a lower limit, too).  You'll have to check all the pointer IDs, though, as pointer id N+1 can remain active after pointer id N has left.  Something like:

```
int activeTouch = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) activeTouch++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dont know the proper way of doing it but a nasty and simple method is coming in my mind. 
Implement inputprocessor [reference for input processor here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) and take a counter variable . Inside its touchdown method increase counter by 1 and inside touchup method decrease counter by 1. the value to counter will give total number of fingures presently touching the screen . Another way to doing it is by pointer in input processor. But I find this method more simpler :)

Answer (score 3):

you can try this:

```
   float Ipsi=0.5;  
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){

        int xTouch = Gdx.input.getX();
        int yTouch = Gdx.input.getY();

        int count=0;
        ArrayList<Integer> lx = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> ly = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        lx.add(xTouch);
        ly.add(yTouch);


        //lx.size()=ly.size()

        if(2<lx.size()){
                for(int i = 0; i < lx.size(); i++){
                            if((lx.get(i)-lx.get(i+1)<Ipsi)&&(ly.get(i)-ly.get(i+1)<Ipsi))
                            {count++;}
                }
        }



    }
```

I did not test the code but i hope it will work. good luck.